# How to add an independent variable constant to OLS formula in statsmodels?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I'm currently working on a data set that is defined by the quadratic function
`y = b0 - b1(x + c)**2`
where b0, b1, and c are non-zero constants I'm hoping to find.

Whilst statsmodels formula ols can find the curve with the formula `'y ~ I(x**2)'` through my x and y values, it is stubbornly stuck to intercepting the x axis at 0.

For example, here is a graph showing the curve fitting of ols (orange) alongside random data with no residual error and the original function (blue):
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Oq0j.png)

I've been reading the [patsy documentation](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formulas.html), but I have not been able to find anything of help so far.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I realised after stepping away for 5 minutes how to "solve" this.

The `(x + c)**2` can be expanded to a polynomial in the form of `x**2 + x + c` which is doable.